# Change text color dynamically based on color behind it (google maps)

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps

I have google maps api as my full screen background that can be resized and moved by the user. I want my text over the map to dynamically change to the inverse of the color behind it. To improve visibility.

So if the user was over the ocean that happened to be 0x0000FF, the text would be 0xFFFF00. This seems crazy to me to get every pixel behind the text unless someone has already made that function.

Does this exist?

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is something  that can't be done, given existing web technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in HTML 5.

Basically you draw an HTML5 canvas, then you need to get the location of the mouse when it moves or on some other event. Given that you're over the canvas, you use `getImageData(x, y, width, height)` to get pixel data of a portion of the selection.

E.g.:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var imgData=ctx.getImageData(10,10,50,50);
```

The data object you get back contains four values for each pixel in your selection, R, G, B and A. RGB are the color channels, A is the Alpha channel (visibility).

Next step would be to convert that value from RGB to Hex, which you could do with a simple helper function:

```
function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
}
```

Now that you have the color, you need to create a mapping or function to get the inverse color. Depending on what effect you want you will have to work this function over a little. Here are two sites that do this type of thing and you can view-source to see their functions and modify if needed.

- [Inverse Color Code Generator](http://www.angelfire.com/ny5/consigliere/inversegenerator.html)
- [Inverse / Opposite Color Generator](http://www.wtv-zone.com/spacemany/inverse.html)

Then you could use JQuery to set the color of  your text.

Comment: Please make your answer more "self-contained".  As it stands, it's useless if the links go dead.  Also, simply linking to other SO questions is discouraged as per reasons discussed at SO Meta site.

Comment: This works. My next question for you is there a way to getContext of just characters instead of a rect?

Comment: The context is `2d` as above. The rectangle datum is `getImageData()`. You can reference HTML5 drawn text on the canvas with `fillText()`. 
If you have a gradient and want a specific hex color code of that exact spot you'll have to hit it precisely by pixel.
Some links to help you out:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/canvas_text_fonts.htm
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-text-font-size/
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/text.html
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_filltext.asp
http://marakana.com/bookshelf/html5_tutorial/canvas.html

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did, I used a transparent background to highlight the text. I guess this may work for you.

[image]